# Organic growth with Lindenmayer Systems

Tags: algorithm

I'm looking for a good way to represent organic growth - especially trees and flowers - using code.

I've found Lindenmayer Systems as a reasonable way to portray this, but need a good place to start programming this.

Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Start by looking at Laurens Lapre's LParser system page at home.wanadoo.nl/laurens.lapre/.

He's made the source code available and it's a great place to kick off from.  The code is highly useful as it is - I once wrapped it up in a dll with minimal changes to employ in a landscape generation program and it worked a treat.

LParser has been around a while, but that doesn't stop it being a great implementation and a really neat bit of coding.

Comment: Link is dead. New one is here: http://laurenslapre.nl/lapre_004.htm but you have to ask for the source. archive.org have an (old?) version: https://web.archive.org/web/20061230173145/http://home.wanadoo.nl/laurens.lapre/source.zip

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much you already know on the topic, but I believe Wikipedia's article on [L-system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) should be a good start.

"using code" is a bit fuzzy, so I can hardly answer. You might find some freeware to experiment with L-systems, you can play with some graphical language like Processing, do that in GDI or Java2D (or 3D), etc.

There are other methods too, my own [Ferns - Static view](http://philho.deviantart.com/art/Ferns-Static-view-85913591) was made with Processing, drawing short lines, using a hierarchical class system to represent trunk, branches and leaves.

Answer (score 0):

There are many LSystem implementations on the web. You can try this one:
http://marvinproject.sourceforge.net/en/plugins/lindenmayer.html

Download the MarvinEditor. There, you can specify your own rules to create your own object by an LSystem.

There is also LSystem in 3D available on the web. Everything depends on your application.